# Why does underscore's _.isUndefined(variable) give an error that variable is not defined?

Tags: javascript, undefined, underscore.js

In Chrome, I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: targetNode is not defined" from this line of code `console.log(_.isUndefined(targetNode));`.

I get the same error when I do `console.log(targetNode === void(0));` and `console.log(targetNode);`.

`typeof targetNode === "undefined"` returns true as expected, but my understanding is that the void(0) comparison is more efficient.

I can get around this by setting a default for `targetNode` or I can just use `typeof targetNode === "undefined"`, but I'm trying to understand why a test for whether a variable is undefined would choke if the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you ask for `targetNode`, it looks for a local variable, then in subsequent parent scopes until it reaches the end of the chain. If it still hasn't found it, there's an error.

`typeof` is special in that it works similar to a `try..catch` around getting the variable, and returning `"undefined"` in the catch. Non-native code (such as `isUndefined`) can't do that since the variable must be resolved in order to pass it to the function.

However, if the symbol is defined, it can be validly passed. For example:

```
function test(param) {
    console.log(_.isUndefined(param));
}
test("argument");
test(); // undefined argument
```

Or another example:

```
function test() {
    console.log(_.isUndefined(foo)); // true, no error due to hoisting
    var foo = 3;
    console.log(_.isUndefined(foo)); // false, foo is defined now.
}
```

You can also specify an explicit source, such as `window.targetNode`. `window` is defined, so the script knows where to look, however the `targetNode` property may not be defined, in which case you get `undefined`.

Comment: In fact, the "X is not defined" error is misleading. It would be better if they had made it "X does not exist" or something similar. Basically anything that doesn't use the word "defined"

Comment: "You haven't declared X in this scope," perhaps...  Thanks again.